# Import Excel spreadsheet where worksheet name varies each month

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to import data from an Excel spreadsheet. The spreadsheet has multiple worksheets, but I'm only interested in the one for components. The worksheet name varies each month, though it always begins with "Components". I'm looking for a way to programmatically find the correct worksheet.

The solution likely lies in getting the worksheet's code name property, but am not sure how to do that.

FWIW, I don't control the spreadsheet and therefore cannot control the use of a named range (they don't use them) nor the naming convention for the worksheets.

```
Private Sub cmdGetFile_Click()
'Import components spreadsheet into components table
    Dim fDlg As FileDialog
    Dim flNme As String
    Dim flChsn As Integer

    Set fDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    fDlg.Title = "Select Products & Components file"
    flChsn = fDlg.Show
    fDlg.FilterIndex = 1

    If flChsn <> -1 Then
       MsgBox "No file selected"
    Else
       flNme = fDlg.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet , acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "component", flNme, -1, [this is where I need help]
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the sheet always located at the same index from left to right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I know the worksheets code name property (it's always Sheet3), I am able to refer to the sheet number and not go through the process of manually typing a name into a dialog box.

A big thank you to Wayne G. Dunn, your clear and well-written answer helped fill in several missing pieces for me! The code for finding spreadsheet names, displaying them and allowing user input I will save as a great example for future use.

So here is the final code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdGetFile_Click()
'Import components spreadsheet into components table
Dim fDlg As FileDialog
Dim flNme As String
Dim flChsn As Integer

Set fDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

fDlg.Title = "Select Products & Components file"
flChsn = fDlg.Show
fDlg.FilterIndex = 1

If flChsn <> -1 Then
   MsgBox "No file selected"
Else
   flNme = fDlg.SelectedItems(1)
End If

' Open the Workbook and display a list of sheet names
Dim excelApp    As Excel.Application
Dim oWB         As Excel.Workbook
Dim oWS         As Excel.Worksheet
Dim strSheets   As String
Dim strRange    As String
Dim i           As Integer
Dim strSheet    As String
Dim iLastrow    As Long
Dim iLastCol    As Long

Set excelApp = New Excel.Application
Set oWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(flNme)
excelApp.Visible = False    'Don't need to see the workbook

' Sheet 3 is the worksheet that I want to import
i = 3
strSheet = strSheets & oWB.Worksheets(3).Name

' Get Cell Range starting in A1
Set oWS = oWB.Sheets(strSheet)

' Get last used row
iLastrow = oWS.Cells(oWS.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Build Import range (Sheet & cells)
strRange = strSheet & "!A1:L" & iLastrow   ' i.e.  "SheetName!A1:P25"

oWB.Close SaveChanges:=False        ' Close, don't save any changes
Set oWB = Nothing
Set excelApp = Nothing

' Import worksheet
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "component", flNme, -1, strRange


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a pattern that would allow you to 'guess' the name of the sheet? i.e. will it be the only sheet that starts with 'Components'? Will there be a date in a certain cell of one of the sheets? In English, describe the way you would select the sheet if you were going to look at it.

The following will list all sheet names in the workbook, then ask you to type in the name of the sheet. If you can define how to identify, then code could be changed to do that.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdGetFile_Click()
    'Import components spreadsheet into components table
    Dim fDlg As FileDialog
    Dim flNme As String
    Dim flChsn As Integer

    Set fDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    fDlg.Title = "Select Products & Components file"
    flChsn = fDlg.Show
    fDlg.FilterIndex = 1

    If flChsn <> -1 Then
       MsgBox "No file selected"
    Else
       flNme = fDlg.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    ' Open the Workbook and display a list of sheet names
    Dim excelApp    As Excel.Application
    Dim oWB         As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oWS         As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim strSheets   As String
    Dim strRange    As String
    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim strSheet    As String
    Dim iLastrow    As Long
    Dim iLastCol    As Long

    Set excelApp = New Excel.Application
    Set oWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(flNme)
    excelApp.Visible = True

    ' Get all Sheet Names
    strSheets = ""
    For i = 1 To oWB.Worksheets.Count
        strSheets = strSheets & oWB.Worksheets(i).Name & vbCr
    Next i

AskAgain:
    ' Display the list
    MsgBox "List of all worksheet names:" & vbCrLf & strSheets

    strSheet = InputBox("Please enter the name of the Worksheet to import.", "Sheet Name?")
    If InStr(1, strSheets, strSheet) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You entered a sheet name that does not exist.", vbOKOnly, "Unknown Sheet Name"
        GoTo AskAgain
    End If

    ' Get Cell Range... Assume range starts in A1????
    Set oWS = oWB.Sheets(strSheet)

    ' Get last used row
    iLastrow = oWS.Cells(oWS.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Build Import range (Sheet & cells)
    strRange = strSheet & "!A1:BM" & iLastrow                   ' i.e.  "SheetName!A1:P25"

    oWB.Close SaveChanges:=False        ' Close, don't save any changes
    Set oWB = Nothing
    Set excelApp = Nothing

    ' Import worksheet
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "component", flNme, -1, strRange         '[this is where I need help]


End Sub
```

Comment: The name of the tab follows a specific pattern: "Components m-d". Example: Components 11-23. If I were going to do it manually, I would look for the tab Components 11-23.